# how to adjust the text in the center of the website without using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin, center

Actually I am trying to make a nice website but the challenge is I can't use
CSS or JavaScript and Now I want to adjust the text at some point in the center.

With the help of the CSS can can do that but I don't know how to do that with HTML

Comment: You cant do that only using html, you need to add css.
<div style="text-align:center">
  This text will be centered.
  <p>So will this paragraph.</p>
</div>
where style is CSS

Comment: I think this 'all depends on what you mean by can't use CSS'. If you can use any sort of HTML attribute you can use a style attribute. I can't think why that would be disallowed - is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Center** Tag which is deprecated

```html
<center>I would not recommend using deprecated tags</center>
```

Comment: As this says, I really would not recommend using deprecated tags, they may stop working at any time. It's not really a suitable answer for 2022.

Answer (score 1):

The align Attribute in HTML is used to specify the alignment of the text content of the element but it is only applicable for some specific elements rest are deprecated.

[Read more here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-align-attribute/)

```html
<div align="center"> Hello World </div>
```

Comment: As this says, I really would not recommend using deprecated tags, they may stop working at any time. It's not really a suitable answer for 2022.

Answer (score 0):

```
<center><p>Type what you want</p></center>
```

or you can use,

```
<p style="position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); padding-bottom: 50px;"></p>
```

Comment: It is already mentioned in the question- "without CSS" and using the <center> tag is already answered. Please check the given answers.

Comment: I really would not recommend using deprecated tags, they may stop working at any time. Recommending the center tag is not really a suitable answer for 2022.